# How to merge two Magento2 instances into two different store views of one instance?

Tags: magento2, multistore, multi-website

I need to merge two Magento(2.4) instances to one website with two different store views.

For example, store Electronics and Store Consumer as two different Magento 2 instances, and I want a new application with two views as Electronics.store.com and Consumer.store.com

I tried to create a store view in-store Electronics and import StoreConsumer's Catalog, Sales, product, customer tables. I'm not sure is this the right approach and I'm getting a lot of conflicts in the process.

Can someone please suggest a better approach or ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There is not an easy way per se to simply merge the data in the two databases, it's simply not the nature of MySql, and the large relational schemas which Magento uses means it wouldn't be as simple as copying data from certain tables into the other database.

The best (and really the only) option you have will be to export your data and then use the same tool to import the data into the other website setup.

My tooling suggestion would be to use uRapidFlow Pro for product information and the built-in Dataflow Profiles for handling customers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will check it